# Need to understand how Row() Function works under SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I had an issue and that is already solved by someone. I want to understand how they solved it.
Here is the link
https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1314166-need-formula-to-post-payments-with-different-dates-frequency-than-column-headers.html#post5320639

I got solution there but I think this platform provides extra explanation of solution, so asking here.

The formula that did the job is as follows:

```
=IF(MATCH($B7,$C$4:$L$4)<=COLUMNS($C7:C7),IFNA(SUMPRODUCT(--(ABS($B7+(MATCH($A7,{"Weekly","Bi-Weekly"},)*7)*(ROW($A$1:$A$99)-1)-AVERAGE(C$4:C$5))<=(C$5-C$4)/2))*$B$1,$B$1*OR(INDEX(ABS(EDATE($B7,(ROW($A$1:$A$50)-1)*MATCH($A7,{"Monthly","Bi Monthly","Quarterly"},))-(C$4+7))<=7,))),0)
```

What I don't understand about this formula is why don't we just put 1 in place of '''ROW($A$1:$A$99)''' or '''ROW($A$1:$A$50)'''

It is throwing me nuts

Comment: Please provide the worksheet from the forum as one needs to be registered there to download it.

Comment: It is usually used to create an array of numbers, which in your case seemed to be happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ROW($A$1:$A$99)` gives 99 results rather than just one result. 
The result would be `{1;2;3;.......;99}`.

So when he entered `ROW($A$1:$A$99)-1` the result would be 
`{0;1;2;.........;98}`.

Lets say the result of `AVERAGE(C$4:C$5)` is `5`. Then `ROW($A$1:$A$99)-1)-AVERAGE(C$4:C$5)` would give 
`{-5;-4;-3;.......;93}`.

`MATCH($A7,{"Weekly","Bi-Weekly"},)` will give a number. So `$B7+(MATCH($A7,{"Weekly","Bi-Weekly"},)*7` will also result in a number. Lets say `10`.

Then `$B7+(MATCH($A7,{"Weekly","Bi-Weekly"},)*7)*(ROW($A$1:$A$99)-1)-AVERAGE(C$4:C$5) will give 10 * {-5;-4;-3;.......;93}` which will give `{-50;-40;...;930}`.

`ABS($B7+(MATCH($A7,{"Weekly","Bi-Weekly"},)*7)*(ROW($A$1:$A$99)-1)-AVERAGE(C$4:C$5))` will remove all minus signs and give `{50;40;...;930}`.

Lets say `(C$5-C$4)/2 is 40. Then (ABS($B7+(MATCH($A7,{"Weekly","Bi-Weekly"},)*7)*(ROW($A$1:$A$99)-1)-AVERAGE(C$4:C$5))<=(C$5-C$4)/2)` will result in `{FALSE;TRUE;....;FALSE}`.

Hope you got the point.

Comment: Thank you for complete explanation. As far as I remember there is a short key to see the array results in cell. What is that key?

Comment: Highlight the section of the formula and press F9.